# Closure handler gives TypeError: foo is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, scope, closures

I'm making a Chrome extension where someone can use the context menu on a particular site, fetch some images from it and load them to a new tab (html template file inside the extension folder).

The thing is that I want the images to be persistent on the tab until it gets closed; so not on **reloads**.

A while ago I found some code that would make that happen, but I constantly get the error that my variable / function is not a function. Any help is greatly appreciated.

The error is throw on the line where `magic(tabId);` is 'called'.

This is what's inside `magic` and `pendingTabs`
[image: output]

[Codebase](https://www.mediafire.com/file/g8upnrwjat1cwcn/stackoverflow+handler.zip/file)

```js
let pendingTabs = new Array();

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(
    function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {

        //Execute the handler
        const magic = pendingTabs[tabId];
        magic(tabId);
        // Delete the handler
        delete pendingTabs[`foobar`];
});

function sendImages(tabId, response, tabTitle) {
    const urls = response.urls;
    
    chrome.tabs.create({url: chrome.runtime.getURL('html/images.html')}, function(tab) {            


        function handler(tabId) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {urls: urls});
        };
        
        pendingTabs[tab.id] = handler;
    });
}
```

Comment: So, did you debug what `pendingTabs` actually contains and what the `tabId` was that's passed to your `onUpdated` handler?

Comment: The `tabId` of the `onUpdated` event is the tab that was loaded / reloaded. And `pendingTabs` seems to contain the ID of the opened tabs that were opened through the context menu that are not yet closed.
I added the output in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add an if on magic() to test if it ain't undefined, then the error vanished like a miracle.